# Calling Classes in foreach only last call works

Tags: php, oop, foreach

Hi and hello to everyone,

I wrote a script which reads a string with one or more lines. These lines will then be read in an array to loop through. Each line contains a class and a method which is called in the foreach. the result of the method called is saved in an var to be returned.

My problem is now that only the last call is executed all other calls before return me that the method does not exists, even so if I change the order of the lines always the last call works. This includes that all method are there and work.

lines look like this

> class_1/method1
>   class_2/method2
>   class_2/method1

the given array i loop through with foreach looks like this

> array(
>
> > [0] => class_1/method1
> >     [1] => class_2/method2
> >     [2] => class_2/method1

now my code converts each item in a new array like this

> array(
>
> > [0] => class_1
> >     [1] => method1

which calls class class_1 and method1 in it

my code is this

```
    public function execute_lines($f){
     $cont = "";  // contains the results of all calls

     if($l = $this->get_line_array($f)){  // $l contains the array of all lines
        foreach($l as $k => $v){        
        if(strpos($v,"/")){     
         $a = explode("/",$v);  // $a contanis the array with the class and method and may be further data to be used in the methods called
         $c = ucfirst($a[0]);   // var of the Class
         $m = strtolower($a[1]);  // var of the methode
         unset($a[0],$a[1]);  // delete the first two items so that the array contains only further data

         if(method_exists($c,$m)){  // see if the method exists
            $x = new $c();  // instantiate the Class
            $cont .=  $x->e($m,$a);  // save result 
            print "-<br />";  // control if the method exits
         }else{
            print "/<br />";  // control if the method does not exists 
         }
        }
     }
    }   
    return $cont;  // returns the cont
    }
```

the result would be

"/"
"/"
and then only the content of the last call where all should apper

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading lines from file, then there's a newline character appended to each line (only the last line doesn't have it, as it seems)

change your code and try again

```
foreach($l as $k => $v){     
    $v = trim($v); // trim whitespace

    if(strpos($v,"/")){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi German Rumm,

that could be the solution I am not able to thest it yet but i will let you know asap

Comment: Hi German Rumm, 

i just make an environmentto test your solution, and viloa it worked out the box. Thankx a millon you saved me hours of debugging and searching

Comment: Hi German Rumm, i tryed in my development environment and indeed it works fine now
Thankx again